# How to open a tab with jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I´m trying to open a tab using jquery, here is my code:

```
$("#ecContenedorFolders").tabs({
     tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon-close'></span></li>"                                                     
});
$("#ecContenedorFolders").tabs("add","#ecApp05","Friends Discussions");
```

As everyone can see i´m using a template, so when i use the 1st 3 lines i get my new tab, but i can switch between prevoius tabs, if i only use the last line i get my new tab, i can switch between tabs, but i can add content. ¿Does anyone knows a way to improuve this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Do you need the code for change the acrive tab?

Comment: I just want to open tabs and load its content with an url.

Comment: Have you read tab documentation on jQueryUI site? 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Comment: You will need to accept the answer. This way the question/answer show up as resolved in search results and such. Please check this link if you need help on how to accept an answer: stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to include `panelTemplate` along with your `tabTemplate`. Something like this:

```
$("#ecContenedorFolders").tabs({
  tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon-close'></span></li>",
  panelTemplate: "<p>Panel Text here</p>"
});

$("#ecContenedorFolders").tabs("add", "#ecApp05", "Friends Discussions");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, 1 more question, if i want to load in panelTemplate an url, lets say google where do i put the url??

Comment: panelTemplate takes in any HTML you want. So to include a url, you could include <a href> in there - something like: `panelTemplate: "<p><a href='www.google.com'>Panel text here</a></p>`

Comment: So, does this answer your question? If so, would you mind accepting this as your answer?

Comment: You will need to accept the answer. This way the question/answer show up as resolved in search results and such. Please check this link if you need help on how to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask